# Understanding why this subset of groups of functions is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $F$ be the set of functions such that $\text{dom}(F)=\mathbb R$ where $\mathbb R$ denotes real numbers.

Consider $F'\subset F$ such that $F'$ is the set of functions where $\text{dom}(F')= \mathbb R$ too but do not take the value $0 \in \mathbb R$.

Is $F'$ a subgroup of $F$ under multiplication?

My attempt:

Let $f'_1,f'_2 \in F'$ then $(f'_1f'_2)(x)=f_1'(x)f'_2(x)$. Neither $f'_i$ takes the value $0$ hence their multiplication doesn't, and the set $F'$ is closed under the induced binary operation.

We can also find the identity element, define it $i'(x)=1$ so that

$$\forall f'_i \in F' , f'_i i'=f'_i$$

The problem is here:

I claim for all $f'_i$ I can find inverses. Only the inverses of the form $\frac{1}{(x-c)^k}$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$ do not exist, since these are not defined for specific values of $x$. But these inverses are the inverses of functions of the form $(x-c)^k$ anyway, which eventually equal $0$ at some point. So I claim I can find inverses. Can someone help me prove this? Any hints?

Comment: I don't understand where you have a problem : you have composition, a unit and inverses...

Comment: $F$ is not a group under multiplication, though you could say $F'$ was a sub*monoid* of $F$ under multiplication which is a group. I have no idea why you talk about $\frac{1}{(x-c)^k}$ at all.  As you state, this function is not defined for all $x \in \mathbb R$ so this function is not an element of $F$ let alone $F'$.  It's pretty clear that for $f \in F'$, $f^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}$ and this is well-defined and satisfies the inverse property, though it wouldn't be well-defined for $f \in F$.

Comment: The problem with saying F' is a [b]sub[/b]group of F is that F itself is not a group with this operation!

Comment: Multiplication. The inverse of $f(x) = 5$ is $g(x) = \frac{1}{5}$ for constant functions and in general the inverse of $f$ is $\frac{1}{f}$ which is defined because $f$ is never zero. No prob, $F'$ is a group with identity $f(x) = 1$. But $F$ isn't a group because functions with zeros don't have multiplicative inverses. Is there something missing from this problem? Something copied down wrong?

Comment: No not missing anything at all. Maybe